# Netsuite soap request SSS_INVALID_HOST_CERT

Tags: post, soap, netsuite

I tried to send some soap requests using: nlapiRequestURL ( url , data, headers, null , 'POST') ;
When I send it to server like:  http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx I receive status code 200, but when I try to do with e.g. https://sprawdz-status-vat.mf.gov.pl I get an error:  SSS_INVALID_HOST_CERT 
Why? Do Netsuite Have some certificate or safe url list?

Answer (score 1):

https://sprawdz-status-vat.mf.gov.pl does not support TLS 1.2 (you can run a test at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to verify this).

NetSuite has deprecated support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1, so any server you try to connect to from NetSuite needs to support TLS 1.2 to work.

See below excerpt from [SuiteAnswer 70534](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70534/kw/nlapirequesturl%20https):

> SuiteScript
>   SuiteScript can be affected when the user is trying to connect to an external resource using SuiteScript Navigation APIs (for example, nlapiRequestURL() ).
>
> See the following examples of errors that might be encountered.
>
> ·         SSS_CONNECTION_CLOSED : usually occurs when the server associated with the URL is unresponsive.
>
> ·         SSS_INVALID_HOST_CERT : usually occurs when the client and server could negotiate the desired level of security. The connection is no longer usable.
>
> ·         Suggested resolution:
>
> Review the URL to which the script is trying to connect to determine whether it is capable of secure communications using TLS 1.2. The URLs can be verified using an external TLS Checker. Once verified, contact the third-party owner of the URL to update their servers to use for TLS 1.2.
>
> See the following examples of external sites to verify your external links:
>
> ·         https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/- Can test the security settings of a URL or web page
>
> ·         https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html- a public API that can be called for testing TLS versions and security settings
>
> For more information, see FAQ: Transport Layer Security (TLS) Deprecations (SuiteAnswers ID: 49076).

Comment: I'm getting these errors in response to SuiteTalk (soap) writes (add/update). I'm assuming that there is some triggered SuiteScript that is resulting in this response. Any ideas on tools or techniques to test this assumption?

Comment: You could go to the "Scripted Records" page for the record type you're writing to and check if it has any deployed user events.

Answer (score 0):

The site's certificate might be outdated or not trusted. This is form the NetSuite Help center:
[image]